# Typescript Array of "keyof typeof enum"

Tags: typescript

Perhaps this isn't the best approach to do this, but I'm storing enum as string and type asserting them into a ts enum.

Though I can't seem to understand the error I'm getting from indexOf.

```
enum MyTypes {
    Cat,
    Mat,
    Sat
};

const example = ["Cat", "Mat"] as Array<keyof typeof MyTypes>;

const str1 = MyTypes[MyTypes.Sat] as string;
const str2 = "Sat";

//This causes error : Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Cat" | "Mat" | "Sat"'
console.log(example.indexOf(str1)); 

//This works fine
console.log(example.indexOf(str2));
```

Comment: The reverse mapping for enums isn't strongly typed, unfortunately.  The quickest way out of this is to assert `const str1 = MyTypes[MyTypes.Sat] as keyof typeof MyTypes` instead of `as string`.

Comment: Do you intend to support something like `example.indexOf("maybe not a valid key")`?

Comment: No all the strings will be in the enum.

Comment: Okay, then you want to test or assert that `str1` is `keyof typeof MyTypes` before passing into `.indexOf()`.  The assertion is the easiest (since *you* know that `MyTypes[MyTypes.Sat]` will be `"Sat"` and not `"some random thing"`)